# Make GTK Entry only focusable on click but gain keyboard control if selected

Tags: gtk3

I have a GtkBox with some GtkEntry elements inside.

Some of them should not be focused by keyboard-tab. Only when clicking on them.
How can this be achieved?

If I set `gtk_widget_set_can_focus` to FALSE for an Entry I solved the focus problem.
But cannot interact with the keyboard anymore.

What is a proper solution for not accepting focus by keyboard but on click within Gtk 3.18.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gtk_container_set_focus_chain()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-set-focus-chain) for that.